# Submitted form results, print to second url?

Tags: javascript, php, json, forms

I have no idea how to do this so looking for some direction. I’ve got a form on ‘page-a’ behind a staff login and a separate public ‘page-b’. I would like the submitted form fields from ‘page-a’ to populate the content on ‘page-b’ until the next time it is submitted.

I was thinking I might need to create a JSON file that outputs the results of the form and call upon that JSON in page-b?

Comment: You can use cookie to store the JSON and a cookie flag to indicate whether or not form has been submitted or not. On `page-b`, you can check the flag and populate the form from cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of passing state between HTML pages on different URLS.

You are correct that the state can be saved by the php application (eg as an associative array or JSON structure).

You would need also to decide if form B was likely to be activated very soon after form A, or "next week" for example. In the latter case you would need to persist the data in a database or file at the server side.

When "form B" needs the data, it would issue an Ajax request on the server. The server would recover the data, format it (eg JSON), and send it back. At the browser end, you then need to populate the "form B" DOM with the recovered data.

Comment: Thank you - this gives me a much better idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about communication between different pages. Hence, to achieve this you can create a singleton storage service and whenever form is submit you can set the response as per the filled data into the storage service from `page-a` and then you can get the stored data into the `page-b`.

```
storageService = {

    formData: {
        name: '',
        email: ''
    },

    SaveState: function () {
        localStorage.setData = JSON.stringify(storageService.formData);
    },

    getState: function () {
        storageService.formData = JSON.parse(localStorage.setData);
    }
}
```